# What game genre do these games fall into?

Tags: terminology

I have taken an interest in a few games I have found on the internet, such as *Fairy Fencer F*, *Hypderdimension Nuptunia*; *Rebirth 1* and *One Piece: Pirate Warriors 3*.

I have looked around, but can not find the classification of these games. I would think strategy, third-person or dungeon explorer?

What game genre do these games fall under?

Comment: In English, generally you should only capitalize the first letter of a word if it starts the sentence, or is a name.

Comment: @Angzuril, it is also considered bad form to point out such inconsistencies here, when we can just as easily edit in the correction.

Comment: @Timelord64 While we can edit things to be easier to read/understand, we do expect some effort on the poster's part, and explaining proper use of capitalization may help the poster so that we don't have to do these sorts of clarity edits in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Neptunia and Fairy Fencer F are Role Playing Games (RPGs). RPGs are a broad and diverse genre, with many subgenres.

One Piece: Pirate Warriors 3 is an action game - but to be more specific it is a Musou (also known as a "Warriors" game overseas). Musou games are a subgenre of action games that focus on large battlefields. You typically control one character and try to lead your army to victory. Typically, Musou games have some RPG elements (like leveling up or character progression).

Answer (score 2):

[Hyperdimension Neptunia](http://www.nisamerica.com/games/neptunia/) and [Fairy Fencer F](http://store.steampowered.com/app/347830/) are both listed as Role Playing Games.

[One Piece: Pirate Warriors 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece:_Pirate_Warriors_3) is considered an Action game.

When these two genres mix together, it is simply refereed to being an Action Role Playing Game This usually infers that the game focuses on real time, action game play, but has elements of player progression and levelling akin to an RPG.

Answer (score 0):

[Fairy Fencer F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Fencer_F) and [Hyperdimension Neptunia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdimension_Neptunia) are **Role Playing Games**.

I couldn't find Rebirth but I assume it's all the same genre and its RPG